# Can't override a simple method

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I've created a new project with two ViewControllers and imported a class that pushes `ViewController` from right to left instead LTR but can't manage to use it. I can see that `pushViewController` inside UIRightToLeft.m is not being called and I don't understand why.
My main goal is to get that working with RTL aniamtion.

```
#import "UIRightToLeft.h"

@implementation UIRightToLeft

- (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    self = [super initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    if (!self)
        return nil;
    return self;
}

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"pushViewController");
    // Add the viewController and a fake controller without animation. Then pop the fake controller with animation.
    UIViewController *fakeController = [[UIViewController alloc] init] ;
    [super setViewControllers:[[self viewControllers] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController, fakeController, nil]] animated:NO];
    [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}

- (void)popViewControllerAnimatedStep2:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // Push the new top controller with animation
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    // Remove the view that should have been popped
    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self viewControllers]];
    [arr removeObjectAtIndex:[[self viewControllers] count]-2];
    [super setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithArray:arr] animated:NO];
}

- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"popViewControllerAnimated");

    if (animated)
    {
        // Save the controller that should be on top after this pop operation
        UIViewController *newTopController = [[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:[[self viewControllers] count]-2];
        // Remove it from the stack. Leave the view that should be popped on top
        NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self viewControllers]];
        [arr removeObjectAtIndex:[[self viewControllers] count]-2];
        [super setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithArray:arr] animated:NO];
        // Schedule the next step
        [self performSelector:@selector(popViewControllerAnimatedStep2:) withObject:newTopController afterDelay:0];
        return [arr objectAtIndex:[arr count]-1];
    }
    return [super popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

@end
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UIRightToLeft.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)pressMe:(UIButton *)sender {
    SecondViewController *next = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];    
}

@end
```

**ViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)pressMe:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

(In my `ViewController` there's only one button draged to the second `ViewController` with push)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The normal push animation is already right to left. Did you mean left to right? Does self.navigationController in ViewController.m point to your UIRightToLeft class or to a UINavigation controller?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the moving between viewcontrollers in the other way apple offers. (for RTL languages). I have no idea where `self.navigationController ` is pointing. This is all the code I have

Comment: Well then just log self.navigationController (in your pressMe method) and see what it returns.

Comment: It crashes . My main problem is that pushViewController isn't getting called

Comment: When does it crash? Do you get a crash log? If it crashes in the pressMe method, put the log first.

Comment: In the above code `pushViewController` inside `UIRightToLeft` is not getting called and logging self.navigtioncontroller gives me `<UINavigationController: 0x71bbf60>`. If i put `@interface SecondViewController : UIRightToLeft` in `SecondViewController.h` I get this:     `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported` with no log at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your error log I think you actually need to have your navigation controller subclass UIRightToLeft.

If you are using a Storyboard, select your navigation controller and set Custom Class to UIRightToLeft.